# ngx-datatable "Cannot read property 'length' of null" after update from v11.0.4 to v11.1.5

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

After upgrading ngx-datatable from `v11.0.4` to `v11.1.5` I am getting an error.

```
 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at DatatableComponent.get [as allRowsSelected] (index.js:4867)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (DatatableComponent.html:18)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14689)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13836)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14187)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14145)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13837)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14187)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14119)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13842)
```

I tried to downgrade to `v11.1.0` but same problem. 
My table definition looks like this:

```
 <ngx-datatable
  fxFlexFill
  #table
  class="material striped"
  [rows]="rows | async"
  [columnMode]="'force'"
  [scrollbarV]="true"
  [scrollbarH]="true"
  [headerHeight]="headerHeight"
  [footerHeight]="50"
  [rowHeight]="rowHeight"
  (scroll)="onScroll($event)"
  [selectionType]="'single'"
  >
```

Data are async so table has no data on init. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You have defined "selectionType" so you need to define "selected" in your datatable and in your component code. Datatable script tries to find selected.length or other related fields from selected row so gives that error.
Add `[selected]="selected"`to your template and add `selected = [];` to your ts file. It must work.